# How to avoid System.TypeLoadException unhandled exception in browser when loading Blazor client-side application

Tags: c#, webassembly, blazor, blazor-client-side

I have a client-side Blazor application, and when I try to run it for debugging from Visual Studio 2019 16.3.0 Preview 2.0, I get this error message in the Chrome browser (seen when debugging using Shift-Alt-D):

blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM: System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000020 from typeref (expected class 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClientJsonExtensions' in assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor, Version=0.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60')

I have set a breakpoint as early I could in Main in Program.cs, but this does not get hit.

I am using Blazor version 3.0.0-preview8.19405.7.
I have been searching for a solution to this problem, but all articles seem to address other issues than mine.

The issue seems to be about Json and HttpClient, so I thought it might have something to do with the upgrade since it was mentioned in the procedure:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-8/

But I actually did not use Json succesfully before upgrading (it was under development), so I don't know for sure if it has something to do with this.

Edit: I have tried to remove the two lines from the code (but kept the reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClient in the project file):

```
result = await httpClient.GetJsonAsync<bool>("uri");
```

and

```
await httpClient.PutJsonAsync("uri", value);
```

This solved the problem, but will of cause leave me without any calls to my backend.

So how can I use httpClient? Or which alternatives do I have?

Edit:

I am creating httpClient using dependency injection in my constructor

```
public class ServiceProxy : IServiceProxy
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
    public ServiceProxy(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:12345"), UriKind.Absolute);
    }

    public async Task<bool> GetResultAsync()
    {
        bool result
        try
        {
            result = await httpClient.GetJsonAsync<bool>("resource");
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException httpRequestException)
        {
            throw new ConnectionException(string.Format("Http Request failed: {0}", httpRequestException.Message), httpRequestException);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

The dependencies are injected from my startup class

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpClient();
        services.AddTransient<IServiceProxy, ServiceProxy>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClient` package, and is it the right version?  See the upgrade blog: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-8/

Comment: Yes, I have this line in my project file:

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClient" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.7" PrivateAssets="all" />`

Comment: Ok, then that is checked. I have no clue what else it could be.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I will have to do more investigation to see if I can make it run again and what did the trick if I do. I will make updates if I come closer to the solution.

Comment: Just to check, are you using the .net core 3 sdk preview 8?

Comment: I verified this using this command:
`C:\Users\Troels>dotnet --list-sdks
2.1.801 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.0.100-preview6-012264 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.0.100-preview8-013656 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]`
Then I uninstalled all SDK's and reinstalled Preview 8:
`C:\Users\Troels>dotnet --list-sdks
3.0.100-preview8-013656 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]`
After this I still got the same error.

Comment: I have now isolated the problematic lines, which was not surprisingly related to the use of httpClient JSON operations.
I will update the post.

Comment: How do you _get_ your httpClient?  Can you show the `@inject`or equivalent?

Comment: I will edit my post to include the creation of httpClient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have discovered the root cause of this problem and thereby found a solution for it.

I upgraded my Visual Studio 2019 to 16.4.0 Preview 1.0, and then something broke, which did not break before.
And when consolidating my NuGet dependencies I was very surprised that one of my .NET Standard dependency projects actually had a reference to Blazor 0.7.0, which was older than the Preview 8 version I was upgrading from.

This reference was probably the cause of my pain!
When that reference was removed, I could not call my httpClient.PutJsonAsync and httpClient.GetJsonAsync any more, because this is probably only implemented in the Blazor version of the HttpClient.

I rewrote my library to use httpClient.PutAsync and httpClient.GetAsync and using Newtonsoft.Json to serialize and deserialize. After fixing some CORS issues in addition, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

When I run into issues like this, I delete the bin and obj folders while my project is closed. I also delete all nuget packages and install them again.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I had done this before and I double checked. This does not solve the problem. But thanks for giving it a try.

Comment: Does this happen when you create a new Blazor project and run it? 
I did run into issues in the past where I would need to create a new project make sure it compiles, then modify my startup.cs, make sure it runs, then I copy my models services and components etc.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to find the error without doing so, but it will probably be the only way.
I can actually make the Blazor template (for client and server) run, I verified that, but there is a lot of stuff in that, I will not need.
I expect to update this post, when I tried to build my own functionality on top of the template, trying to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Client side blazor does not support `IHttpClientFactory`.
Client side `HttpClient` is not the same as in server side or other version. It is a wrapper of the `XMLHttpRequest` in the browser. (Additionally layered over typescript)

> [Blazor client-side apps call web APIs using a preconfigured
>   HttpClient service. Compose requests, which can include JavaScript
>   Fetch API options, using Blazor JSON helpers or with
>   HttpRequestMessage.
>
> Blazor server-side apps call web APIs using HttpClient instances
>   typically created using IHttpClientFactory. For more information, see
>   Make HTTP requests using IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core.][1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

On client side the `HttpClient` is out of the box included in the DI. You can use that to make http calls.

Inject it to code into constructor:

```
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

public YourClassName(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    _httpClient = httpClient;
}

//Use the _httpClient in other methods as usual
```

Injecting into a property

```
[Inject]
public HttpClient MyHttpClient { get; set; }
```

Injecting into a blazor page

```
@inject HttpClient MyHttpClient

code {
   //Use the MyHttpClientin other methods as usual
}
```

[Additional resources for DI in blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I am sure this is necessary but unfortunately not sufficient.
I have implemented the use of the client-side `HttpClient` included in the DI, but I still have exactly the same error.

Comment: Do you have the solution split up into multiple projects? Usual case for `TypeLoadException` is that the included project(s) are targeting the wrong framework. If so please check if all the referenced projects are targeting `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>`.

Comment: I do have my solution split up, but every dependency is targetting .NET Standard 2.0 as you suggest.